Python Parallel Procesing
In my case, the multiprocessing run is only needed in a class method I built to call from a script. It is being blocked and I do not understand why. I have already incorporated some suggestions given by SO collaborators, but the problem persists. In my code below, it is printed IN and nothing happens afterwards. Can someone please help me to overcome this issue? By the way, I am trying to solve N independent constrained LSQ problems, where N can be very large. I used to perform this task in Matlab, using the straightforward command parfor. Thanks.
    def U_matrix(self, V):
        U = np.zeros((0, self.c))
        min_val = 1e-10

        args = range(0, self.N)
        with multiprocessing.Pool()as pool:
            print('IN')
            u = pool.starmap(self.lsqSOLUTION, zip(repeat(V), args))
            print('OUT')
            vector = np.array(u)
            U = np.vstack((U, vector))
        
        U[np.absolute(U) < min_val] = 0        
        return np.transpose(U)

The lsqSOLUTION method solves constrained LSQ problem, one at a time. It is located within the class but out of U_matrix method.
I have followed several suggestion given by SO collaborators, which helped improve the initial solution. Likewise the method, I am blocked now! I have already tried to replace with... by pool = .... No success again
